# Are there any other keywords that can be accessed using the global namespace scope resolution operator?

Tags: c++, new-operator, resolution, operator-keyword, delete-operator

The global new and delete can be used like normal, but you can also prefix the :: operator to them and it will work the same. 
Are there any other keywords that have this same behaviour?

Comment: You might want to put a specific language tag on this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can also scope `operator` keyword, like `::operator+(a, b)`.

I believe `new`, `delete` and `operator` are the only ones in standard C++ that allow this.